# Disable header and footer on custom url with :id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to disable my `Header` and `Footer` components on my `Product` page. Here is my code:

```js
const HeaderRoute = useCallback(
    () =>
      !["/create", "/sign-up", "/sign-in", "/product"].includes(
        window.location.pathname
      ) && <Header />,
    []
  );
```

However, my `Product` component url contains custom `:id` or `path="/product/:id"` :

```js
<Route exact path="/product/:id" component={Product} />
```

The header doesn't render on the other urls, but it does on the `/product:id` url for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: The `includes` function checks for exact matches and `product/someId` is not contained in the array. You could try using [regex](https://regexr.com/) or include the header in a wrapper component for the app

Comment: @AramBecker can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The method `includes` searches for exact matches, so that `['/product'].includes('product')` is false.

If you want to see if a string *matches inside* another you can use `match`.

Your condition will be like:

```
const HeaderRoute = useCallback(
    () =>
      !["/create", "/sign-up", "/sign-in", "/product"].some(path => 
         window.location.pathname.match(path)
      ) && <Header />,
    []
  );
```

### Working example

```js
function showHeader(pathname) {
  return !["/create", "/sign-up", "/sign-in", "/product"].some(path => pathname.match(path));
}

console.log(showHeader("/product:id")); // false
console.log(showHeader("/create")); //false
console.log(showHeader("/create/new:id")); //false
console.log(showHeader("/anotherPage")); //true
```